# WinJs getFileAsync without stating a folder first

Tags: javascript, windows, winjs

I have a string to the path of a file, and i would like to get the file.  So far i have only found this, which relies on the file being within a specified folder, or a child of this folder.

```
var rootFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;

rootFolder.getFileAsync('MY_FILE_PATH_FROM_ROOT').then(function (file) {

});
```

By rootFolder points to a folder where the app is installed, something like C:\Program Files....

What if i have a filePath string of something like C:\MyFiles\Picture\Pic_123.png.  How would i get this file?

Sorry i am new to WinJs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of simple once you see the API.  Use

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync('YOUR_FILE_PATH')
    .then(function (file) {

    });
```